# Search for a minimum and display the corresponding identifier

Tags: r

I have been trying to solve this problem for several days.
Originally I have tree position data in relation to a centre (angle to north and centre and distance). I have calculated the coordinates for each tree to have their individual position in space.

I then have to find the minimum distance between the different trees and note the nearest tree and its distance.

I started to reason with a double loop, but I always got a result only for the last row of my table.
I finally managed to calculate the minimum distance between a tree i and its first neighbour. But I can't find the number corresponding to the nearest tree.
Example: tree 1 has trees 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 as neighbours; the distance is minimum between tree 1 and 3, I would like my code to return the number 3 for i = 1 (tree number 1).
Here is my code, hoping that my explanations are clear enough and that you can help me
thank you very much

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

code:

```
SM = data_RSD %>% mutate(Xc= Dist*sin(Angle*(pi/200)), Yc= Dist *cos(Angle*(pi/200)))

SM$Dist_min=0
SM$Nb_tree_min=0


for(i in 1:dim(SM)[1]){
  x<-sqrt((SM$Xc[1:dim(SM)[1]]-SM$Xc[i])^2+(SM$Yc[1:dim(SM)[1]]-SM$Yc[i])^2) #distance
  SM$Dist_min[i]= (min(x[x > 0]))
  SM$Nb_tree_min[i]= SM$Number[(min(x[x > 0]))]
  i<-i+1
}
```

Comment: Look at the `which.min()` function.

Answer (score 0):

one approach (without resorting to dedicated spatial libraries), adapt to your data structure as seen fit:

create example dataframe **df**:

```
library(dplyr) ## for dataframe manipulations later on

set.seed(4711) ## ensure same random values for reproduction

df <- data.frame(id = letters[1:5],
                 x = runif(5),
                 y = runif(5),
                 )

## > df
##  
##   id         x          y
## 1  a 0.9656003 0.61809459
## 2  b 0.5606107 0.34204836
## 3  c 0.9147251 0.16194603
## 4  d 0.1829564 0.27060681
## 5  e 0.8842138 0.07892783
```

generate distance matrix:

```
distance_matrix <- df %>%
  select(x, y) %>%
  dist(.) %>% ## calculate distances
  as.matrix %>% ## convert it to matrix
   `+`(., diag(NA, dim(.))) ## see 1)

## 1) a shorthand for replacing the diagonal (distances of points to
## themselves) with NAs so that points are not returned as their own
## nearest neighbours
```

identify ID and distance to nearest neighbour from distance matrix:

```
df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(
    neighbour_distances = list(distance_matrix[id,]), ## see 2)
    nearest_neighbour = which.min(neighbour_distances) %>% names,
    distance = neighbour_distances[nearest_neighbour]
  )

## 2) you can store not only single values but vectors and many object
## classes (e.g. models) in a column by wrapping them in a list
```

output:

```
## # A tibble: 5 x 6
## # Rowwise: 
##   id        x      y neighbour_distances nearest_neighbour distance
##   <chr> <dbl>  <dbl> <list>              <chr>                <dbl>
## 1 a     0.966 0.618  <dbl [5]>           c                   0.459 
## 2 b     0.561 0.342  <dbl [5]>           d                   0.384 
## 3 c     0.915 0.162  <dbl [5]>           e                   0.0884
## 4 d     0.183 0.271  <dbl [5]>           b                   0.384 
## 5 e     0.884 0.0789 <dbl [5]>           c                   0.0884
```

quick visual plausibility check of results:

```
df %>%
  ggplot() + geom_text(aes(x, y, label = id)) +
  coord_fixed()
```